# How to get all github users with push access on an organization repo using teams

Tags: github

I am trying to get the list of all users with push access to a repo in my organization. At first glance https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#list seemed like it would do the trick. Simply look through those users for permission=push. But that does not appear to return all of the users.

I am in fact using github.com/google/go-github/ to access the github API, so it is possible the problem is not in github, but in go-github. But I don't really know...

In my organization we have 2 teams. Say team1 and team2. Some people are in both team1 and 2. Some are only in one or the other. Both teams have the same (2) repositories. Team 1 has read/pull permission on the repos, team 2 has write/push.

When I call ListCollaborators() I only get those users in team1. Not the users in team2. (So when I cut that list down to only those with permission=push I end up with the intersection of team1 and 2, when in fact I want team2)

I also considered if it would be possible to just get all of the users in the organization (/v3/orgs/members/#members-list) but I could not find an API which would let me check if a user had write/push permission to a given repo. (I could also maybe list all of the teams and instead check if those had write/push access to the repo, but I don't know how to do that either)

[EDIT]

Maybe there is a better way, but I did find that I could get all of the teams in the organization, then use https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#get-team-repo to find out if the team had write permission on the repo. I could then get the list of all users in those teams. Its ugly, but it's working.

[EDIT]

So getting all teams and all team-repos is actually insufficient. You can have "Outside contributors" with permission to push to repos which are not a member of the organization nor a member of a team. So this is still not completely answered.